# Application executes but sometimes fails to show

Tags: delphi, unidac

This is the project source:

```
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;
  Application.ShowMainForm := False;
  Application.CreateForm(TMain_Form, Main_Form);
  Application.CreateForm(TData_Module, Data_Module);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm5, Form5);
  Login;
  Application.Run;
```

Order of creation is :
Main_Form,Data_Module,Form5

Uniconnection timeout is 30 seconds.

I am connecting to SQL Server .

And this I have in my mainForm :

```
procedure Login;
begin
  with TUniConnectDialog.Create(nil) do
  try
    try
      Application.MainForm.Hide;
      if not Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1.Execute then
        Application.Terminate

      else
        Application.MainForm.Show
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do    begin
       ShowMessage('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName);
       ShowMessage('Exception message = '+E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And yet, sometimes my connect dialog fails to show and the application runs
silently in the background.I have to use Windows Task Manager to end it.

I tried using eureka to debug it but it fails to show me any error.
Application executes but fails to show.
This happens maybe in 3 out of 10 cases.
Now I cant figure out what am I doing wrong here.

Edit:

```
procedure Login;
begin
 with Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1.Create(nil) do
      try
      Application.MainForm.Hide;
        if not Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1.Execute then
        Application.Terminate

      else
        Application.MainForm.Show
    finally
    //  Free;
    end;
    end;
```

EDIT 2: This does not work either.

Comment: You appear to be using two UniConnectDialog objects. Is that intentional? Also you are swallowing the exception effectively so I am not sure how eureka would handle that, and ShowMessage I think shows as a child of the main form, which is hidden, so you won't see them. I would try commenting out the exception handler and see if it fails. I would also try not hiding the main form to see if this makes the error clearer.

Comment: @Dsm UniConnectDialog is supposed to be one.

Comment: Surely `with TUniConnectDialog.Create(nil) do` and `if not Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1.Execute then` refer to two different instances, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Missed that. Based on your suggestion I edited the code. It seems to work for the time being. :)

Comment: No, your edit is wrong. You should not need to create Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1 or if you do you need to use Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1 := TUniConnectDialog.Create(???)... well I would use Data_Module for ??? not nil.

Comment: @Dsm mind explaining ? I dont follow you ...

Comment: If TUniConnectDialog is a dialog component dropped onto your data form you don't need to create it. It will be created with the data module . But in any event you call a constructor via its class, not an instance, as you do in your edit.

Comment: @Dsm so I do :  with TUniConnectDialog.Create(Application) do ?

Comment: See my answer (although it (probably) is not the whole story) - I just don't know how else to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete solution (or may be - hard to tell) but corrects the errors in the edit of the main question. I couldn't do it in comments, unfortunately.

```
procedure Login;
begin
  // with Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1.Create(nil) do
  // 1) Don't use 'with' - it just creates ambiguity
  // 2) You probably don't need to create the dialog
  // 3) If you do the format should be:
  //    Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1 := TUniConnectDialog.Create(???)
      try
      Application.MainForm.Hide;
        if not Data_Module.UniConnectDialog1.Execute then
        Application.Terminate

      else
        Application.MainForm.Show
    finally
    //  Free;
    end;
  end;
```